# Am I allowed to remove left recursion like this?

Tags: context-free, left-recursion

I have:

```
<A> -> <B> <C> <D>
<D> -> <D> <C>
<D> -> lambda
```

Since `<D>` goes to lambda, can I just change my language to:

```
<A> -> <B> <C> <D>
<D> -> <C> <D>
<D> -> lambda
```

thereby removing the left recursion? If I do the alpha beta removal method it creates an extra state that seems like junk.

Comment: This "extra state that seems like junk" is not *always* junk, and this is important. In this particular case it is unnecessary, but it is important that you understand why. Hint: try to prove that if $D$ *didn't* just "go to lambda", then the extra production rule would be necessary.